# Android HttpUrlconnection not posting to URL

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to submit a form from android emulator and it is not posting. I checked the URL in the browser and completed the form and it posts a new record into MySQL but from android it doesn't. I have been searching here for related threads but can't find the issue with my code this is what I have
(I have internet and network access uses permission)

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        Submit= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DownloadFilesTask newtask = new DownloadFilesTask();
                newtask.execute("http://10.0.2.2:9999/api/registration");
            }

        });

    }
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


            try {
                TextView username,password;
                username= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
                password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:9999/api/registration");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
                values.put("username", username.toString());
                values.put("password", password.toString());

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                writer.write(String.valueOf(values));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();


                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;

            }
        }

       // @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
if(result==true)
{
    Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
            else
{Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        }
    }
```

and the Toast at the bottom always goes to fail. As you can see from my code I am trying to insert a username and password.

**This is my logcat**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
 at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1633)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1633)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1633)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-23 21:38:17.729       78-228/system_process A/NetworkStats﹕ problem reading network stats
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$1.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:612)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$1.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:612)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:743)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
            at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$1.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:612)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-23 21:38:19.079        78-90/system_process E/WindowManager﹕ Window Session Crash
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41598ea8 does not exist
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7163)
            at com.android.server.wm.Session.setWallpaperPosition(Session.java:360)
            at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:419)
            at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:111)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 667-749/com.android.contacts E/DefaultVoicemailNotifier﹕ 
 No voicemails to notify about: clear the notification.
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: have you given NETWORK permission in your android config?

Comment: Yes I have this   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first comment the line setDoInput

Convert your contenvalues  like a URL

```
String body = "?username=user&password=password"
```

And write this in URL

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

And never, never call these lines inside an doInBackground:

```
TextView username,password;
username= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Never interact with UI in doInBackground, use onPreExecute and onPostExecute instead.

The body var is for test, if you can get bytes of contenvalues you are welcome.

Don't forget call

```
conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: perfect thanks a lot that has gotten my code working.